# Do we have any options in SQL for VLOOKUP?

Tags: sql, vlookup

I am looking for an alternative solution for VLOOKUP in SQL

Comment: Despite superficial similarities, SQL tables and spreadsheets are *not* the same. E.g. in spreadsheets, rows and columns are interchangeable whereas in SQL, they're completely different concepts. Don't approach problems in SQL from a spreadsheet mindset.

Comment: There are multiple different options -- but none is an exact match.  You would need to ask a question with a *specific example* to determine what approach is best for your situation.  Also tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It is called JOIN(OUTER/INNER,LEFT/RIGHT)

Comment: . . `VLOOUP()` takes an optional final argument which is a boolean -- and allows non-exact matches.  Although this could be implemented in SQL, it is not as simple as `JOIN`.